# How do I map a mysql entity attribute of type SET into spring entity?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm doing some exercises with mysql sample database sakila. In the table "film" I have the field "special_features" that is a SET attribute, how can I map it to spring entity? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JbdcTemplate ,you can use the RowMapper https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html. if you are using Spring Data JPA then it will be more easier for you https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference.